# State doesn't update properly when making a post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, redux

Hey guy's I have no idea why my state isn't updating in the DOM, I'm sure I'm missing some key react principal. [Heres the photo of what my DOM looks like after I submit a post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HMDD.png)

Instead of the post displaying when I click submit with filled out info, a blank post is shown. And I have to manually reload the page before it shows what was added. I think I'm actually battling some sync issues, please let me know what I can do if you see anything.

I will put the most relevant file's code below and also attache the repository at the bottom if you want to have a complete look.

dataActions.js

```
import { SET_POSTS, LOADING_DATA, DELETE_POST, POST_PRODUCT, SET_ERRORS, CLEAR_ERRORS, LOADING_UI } from "../types";
import axios from 'axios';
//GET ALL PRODUCTS
export const getPosts = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_DATA });
    axios.get('/posts')
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_POSTS,
                payload: res.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_POSTS,
                payload: []
            })
        })
}
//POST PRODUCT
export const postProduct = (newPost) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_UI });
    axios.post('/post', newPost)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: POST_PRODUCT,
                payload: res.data
            })
            console.log("success");
            dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response.data
            })
        })
}
//DELETE PRODUCT
export const deletePost = (postId) => (dispatch) => {
    axios.delete(`/post/${postId}`)
        .then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: DELETE_POST, payload: postId })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

dataReducer.js

```
import { SET_POSTS } from '../types';
import { LOADING_DATA, DELETE_POST, POST_PRODUCT/*, SET_POST*/ } from '../types';

const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    post: {},
    loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case LOADING_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case SET_POSTS:
            return{
                ...state,
                posts: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }
        case DELETE_POST:
            let index = state.posts.findIndex(post => post.postId === action.payload);
            state.posts.splice(index, 1);
            return {
                ...state
            }
        case POST_PRODUCT:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: [action.payload, ...state.posts]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

PostProduct.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import MyButton from "../util/MyButton";

//MUI Stuff
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DeleteOutline from "@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline";
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
//REDUX
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { postProduct } from "../redux/actions/dataActions";

const styles = {
  form: {
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  image: {
    margin: "20px auto 20px auto",
    width: "50px"
  },
  pageTitle: {
    margin: "10px auto 10px auto"
  },
  textField: {
    margin: "10px auto 10px auto"
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 20,
    postition: "relative"
  },
  customError: {
    color: "red",
    fontSixe: "0.8rem",
    marginTop: 10
  },
  progress: {
    position: "absolute"
  },
  submitButton: {
      position: "relative"
  },
  progressSpinner: {
      position: 'absolute'
  },
  closeButton: {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: '90%',
      top: '10%'
  }
};

class PostProduct extends Component {
    state = {
        open: false,
        name: '',
        errors: {}
    };
    UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if (nextProps.UI.errors) {
            this.setState({
                errors: nextProps.UI.errors
            })
        }
    }
    handleOpen = () => {
        this.setState({ open: true })
    }
    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false })
    }
    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
    }
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.postProduct({ body: this.state.body })
    }
    render(){
        const { errors } = this.state;
        const { classes, UI: {loading }} = this.props;
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <MyButton onClick={this.handleOpen} tip="Post a Product">
              <AddIcon />
            </MyButton>
            <Dialog
              open={this.state.open}
              onClose={this.handleClose}
              fullWidth
              maxWidth="sm"
            >
              <MyButton
                tip="close"
                onClick={this.handleClose}
                tipClassName={classes.closeButton}
              >
                <CloseIcon />
              </MyButton>
              <DialogTitle>Post the new Product</DialogTitle>
              <DialogContent>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <TextField
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    lable="Post Product"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="name"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="images"
                    type="text"
                    lable="image"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="image"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="itemCategory"
                    type="text"
                    lable="Painting"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="Painting"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="link"
                    type="text"
                    lable="link"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="https://etsy.com"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="info"
                    type="text"
                    lable="blah blah blah"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="info"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="price"
                    type="text"
                    lable="Price"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="75.99"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="available"
                    type="text"
                    lable="available?"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="true"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="highEnd"
                    type="text"
                    lable="High-end or not?"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="false"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.submitButton}
                    disabled={loading}
                  >
                    Submit
                    {loading && (
                      <CircularProgress
                        size={30}
                        className={classes.progressSpinner}
                      />
                    )}
                  </Button>
                </form>
              </DialogContent>
            </Dialog>
          </Fragment>
        );
    }


} // END CLASS

PostProduct.propTypes = {
    postProduct: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    UI: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    UI: state.UI
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { postProduct })(withStyles(styles)(PostProduct))
```

The front end code is in this repository here: https://github.com/jIrwinCline/planum-front

Thanks for any help. I know this is a big question...

Comment: Is it correct that you use the action `getPosts()` to fetch in all the post at initial mount? So `SET_POSTS` will be initial data, and then you append new elements to that list with `POST_PRODUCT`?  I would then guess that the structure of these to events have some differences, that you are doing something wrong in `POST_PRODUCT`. I cant see the structure of your `post` array, so its a little bit difficult to tell. You could try to change ` posts: [action.payload, ...state.posts]` to ` posts: [...state.posts, action.payload]` to make sure you dont overwrite something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post product thunk sets `LOADING_UI` and then `POST_PRODUCT` if successful.

```
export const postProduct = (newPost) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_UI });
    axios.post('/post', newPost)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: POST_PRODUCT,
                payload: res.data
            })
            console.log("success");
            dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response.data
            })
        })
```

In your reducer, there is no `LOADING_UI` case and the`POST_PRODUCT` case just sets the post data but doesn't turn loading off:

```
case POST_PRODUCT:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: [action.payload, ...state.posts]
            }
```

I suspect you have to add a `LOADING_UI` case to your reducer and ensure that `POST_PRODUCT` sets loading to false when it updates your store with the new posts.